# How to check if device has GSM or GPS ability?

Tags: android

I tried to upload application that turns off GPS and enables "plane mode", and I got rejected because of error that cause **Galaxy Tab Wi-Fi(M180W)**. So I need some help to determine whether device has plane mode feature or GPS.

GPS:

```
//gps
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
        appPrefs.setGPS(manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
        if (manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && manager!=null){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS );
        startActivity(myIntent);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please turn off GPS and hit back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
```

Plane mode:

```
// plane mode
        if (option){
            appPrefs.setCBoption(true);
            // read the airplane mode setting
            boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
                      getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), 
                      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;

            // toggle airplane mode
            Settings.System.putInt(
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

            // Post an intent to reload
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
            intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: You can't enable GPS manually. The User should do that. And even if you find a way, it may not be applicable for all devices.

Comment: Yes, I know I make a pop up window, where user can choose it :)

Comment: I need a way to determine whether device has this feature or this feature is "null" in that device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For GSM :

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if (manager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM)
```

For GPS :

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

ArrayList<String> names = (ArrayList<String>) locationManager.getProviders(false);
```

if names is empty, you don't have GPS

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use `PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(...)`.

```
/** Returns true if this device has support for GSM, otherwise false. */
public static boolean hasGsmSupport(Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY_GSM);
}
```

and...

```
/** Returns true if this device has support for GPS, otherwise false. */
public static boolean hasGpsSupport(Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
}
```